# Button click event is not firing inside update panel

Tags: updatepanel

I have a .aspx page with multiple update panels . Script manager tag is defined in master page already. In .aspx page within update panel I have 2 drop-down list <asp:DropDown…. And a text box and a button. Now I need partial post back so I need update panel. Now in my case button click event is firing first time only. What to do. Everything I tried ….

Put update mode to always and also condition and childrentrigger=yes and also I tried with Triggers tag also